# Number Palindrome Program

Tags: java, logic, palindrome

I am stuck on this simple problem and can't figure out the bug. This is a method that returns whether the given number is a palindrome or not. However, every time it is returning false even though it's returning the correct palindrome. Please help.

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
                int reverse = 0;
        
                while (number != 0) {
        
                    reverse *= 10;
                    reverse += (number % 10);
                    number /= 10;
                }
                System.out.println(reverse);
        
                return (reverse == number);
            }
```

Comment: `while (number != 0)` means that `number` will be 0 when the loop ends, so `reverse == number` *after* the loop might as well be `reverse == 0`, which of course isn't what you want. Don't modify the parameter value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're modifying `number` as you go, so `number` at the end is not the `number` that was passed in.

Maybe something like...

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(final int originalNumber) {
    int number = originalNumber;
    int reverse = 0;

    while (number != 0) {

        reverse *= 10;
        reverse += (number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(reverse);

    return (reverse == originalNumber);
}
```

Comment: It is generally recommended that you never modify parameters, which can actually be enforced by the compiler if you have the parameters `final`. It would therefore be a better solution for the loop to modify the local variable, not the parameter, so you can compare with the actual parameter at the end.

Comment: `int number = originalNumber; while (number != 0) { XXX; number /= 10; }` can then be written as a `for` loop, keeping the loop logic together: `for (int number = originalNumber; number != 0; number /= 10) { XXX; }`